# PHP: If one clear member, redirect to user profile

Tags: php

Yes so i want to, in the search results, if there´s one that matches completly of what you have entered, then it should go to profil.php?id=$row[id]

I tried by doing this:

```
$full_name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["search"]);
$Matchy = $get["firstname"] . " " . $get["lastname"];
    if($full_name == $Matchy){
    echo "redirect me";
    }
```

Is this ok? It seems to work, but maybe there's a better solution for doing this?

And how do I redirect without using header, as it already begun at the top..?

Answer (score 0):

Sure it'll work, just remember a few things.

This will make usernames (names) case sensitive, and someone will have to only enter 1 space, they'll have to remember to do firstname lastname, not lastname firstname like some might assume. Depending on how you are retrieving $get it could be faster and more efficient to do a direct DB look up.

Edit:
to make them not sensitive, you can lowercase them, either store them lowered cased or just lower case for comparason. i.e

```
$full_name = strtolower(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["search"]));
$Matchy = strtolower($get["firstname"]) . " " . strtolower($get["lastname"]);
```

Comment: How to make them not sensitive? $get is while($get = mysql_fetch_array  ($result1)){

Comment: Ok last, how do you redirect without header? :P should i use javascript?

Comment: @user457827 without headers, yes javascript can work or use meta refresh, javascript might be cleanest

Comment: header('Location: /somewhere/'); Note: Make sure there's no output prior using header()

Comment: @Mikey1980 "Ok last, how do you redirect without header? :P should i use javascript? – user457827" I think he knows how to do the header()

Answer (score 0):

```
$full_name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["search"]);
$Matchy = $get["firstname"] . " " . $get["lastname"];
    if($full_name == $Matchy){
    echo "redirect me";
    }
```

This is an **another** way to do it: (and taking Viper's comment in consideration)

1. concatenate strings
2. make them common case (lower / upper)
3. remove spaces in them. <= This is important, where end user may include extra spaces during start / end of between names.. EG: instead of `"Tom Cruise"` I may write in " Tom Cruise " , trim will remove spaces from both ends, so , you can use that individually in the get[fname] and get[lname]

.

```
$Matchy = trim(strtolower($get["firstname"])) . " " . trim(strtolower($get["lastname"]));


if(strtolower($full_name) == $Matchy){
    echo "redirect me";
 }
```

Comment: @Stewie why in the world would you remove spaces then do a comparison? you're going to have usernames matching that should NOT match.

Comment: And please give me an example of: "you're going to have usernames matching that should NOT match"

Comment: easy, 2 names: 'jay sonny' AND 'jayson ny' separate (with space) they're 2 different names, but if you remove the space they're the same, it'll happen with plenty of other names. username or names either way you're going to be linking to the incorrect page/user. I down voted because I do not recommend your answer, you clearly state "This is the best way to do it:" I disagree with that, and I think I just showed it. I don't want the OP taking the wrong advice. I don't mind people disagreeing and giving something else, but here you clearly state your way is "best".

Comment: ^^ Thanks for the lesson ;) I have updated the answer, I agree. I don't want anyone to get wrong information too.